# Paypal Orders API Mixed Single & Subscription Purchase

Tags: php, paypal

I'm currently using the Paypal Orders API (v2) to process multiple items from a website's cart. Everything is working smoothly, but I now want to integrate subscriptions for some products. Basically, when they add the item to the cart it should be a subscription after checking out, that will charge money monthly.

Is it possible to combine having single purchases & subscriptions in a single checkout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible unless you use a plan with a `setup_fee` that corresponds to the amount you want to charge immediately, or add an additional TRIAL billing_cycle with a different amount.

A `plan_id` can be overridden with other `plan` details at the time of [creating the subscription](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_create), be it creation via API or with the JS SDK `actions.order.create`